# Response object doesn't return the data I want to scrape from a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the titles, description, partners etc from this search result using requests and BeautifulSoup in Python. But the response object doesn't return the data which I need and which is shown when I visit the URL in the browser

Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://partneredge.sap.com/content/partnerfinder/search.html#/search/results?itemsPerPage=10&sortBy=shortname&sortOrder=asc'
count = 0

response = requests.get(url)

if response.ok:

    response = response.text
    content = bs(response , 'lxml')


    results = content.find_all('li',class_='search-results__item')

    for each in results:
        count+=1
        title = each.find('header').find('a').text.strip()
        link = each.find('header').find('a').get('href')
        print('********************* '+str(count)+' *********************')
        print('Title: {}\nLink: {}\n'.format(title,link))
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is loaded with `JavaScript` event which render it's data dynamically once the page loads.

`requests` library will not be able to render `JavaScript` on the fly. so you can use `selenium` or `requests_html`. and indeed there's a lot of modules which can do that.

Now, we do have another option on the table, to track from where the data is rendered. I were able to locate the [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) request which is used to retrieve the data from the `back-end` `API` and render it to the users side.

> You can get the `XHR` request by open [Developer-Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and check [Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and check `XHR/JS` requests made depending of the type of call such as `fetch`

Below is a simple call where the limit is `maximum` of `600` configured by `parameter` `size`

So you will need to `loop` over by increment `600` each time till you reach total of `4803` which is the max result for `sap`. Below you do have a valid `JSON` dict, which you can access it using the `keys`.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0",
}

data = "{\"returnCount\":{},\"repository\":\"partnerfinder\",\"type\":\"content\",\"filters\":[{\"field\":\"AUTHOR\",\"values\":[\"PWP\"],\"type\":\"exact\"}],\"returnResults\":{\"sort\":[{\"field\":\"SHORTNAME\",\"order\":\"asc\"}],\"page\":{\"size\":600},\"outputFields\":[\"TITLE\",\"EMAIL\",\"PARTNERID\",\"DESCRIPTION\",\"PHONE\",\"AWARDID\",\"FOCUSAREA\",\"LEVEL\",\"URL\",\"SHORTNAME\"]}}"


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.post(url, data=data, headers=headers).json()
        # print(r.keys())
        # humanview = json.dumps(r, indent=4)
        for item in r["result"]["results"]["results"]:
            print(item["TITLE"])


main("https://partneredge.sap.com/bin/fiji/es/search-results")
```

Sample of output:

```
 IBM World Trade Corporation - Egypt Branch
 Origo hf. 
2BM A/S 
Accenture (China) Co. Limited 
Accenture (UK) Ltd. 
ACCENTURE - CONSULTORES DE GESTÃO, S.A.
Accenture AB 
Accenture AG 
Accenture AS 
Accenture Australia Pty Ltd 
Accenture B.V. 
Accenture Chile Asesorías y Serv. Ltda. 
Accenture Company Limited 
Accenture do Brasil Ltda. 
Accenture GmbH 
Accenture GmbH 
Accenture Inc. 
Accenture Japan Ltd. 
Accenture Limited LAGOS
Accenture LLC 
Accenture Middle East BV 
ACCENTURE OUTSOURCING SERVICES, S.A. 
Accenture Pte Ltd 
Accenture S.A. 
Accenture S.p.A. 
Accenture S.R.L. 
ACCENTURE SAS 
Accenture Saudi Arabia Limited 
Accenture Sdn Bhd 
Accenture Solutions Private Limited 
Accenture Solutions Sdn Bhd 
Accenture Sp. z o.o. 
Accenture Technology Solutions Oy 
Accenture Technology Ventures B.V.branch 
Accenture, Inc. 
Accenture, S.L. 
Accenture 
Accenture 
addIT Dienstleistungen GmbH & Co KG 
advanced business Consulting GmbH 
Ageless LLC 
All for One Group AG 
All for One Steeb GmbH 
All Tax Platform - Soluções Tributárias S.A.
AMAZON WEB SERVICES INC 
AO Deloitte and Touche CIS 
Apigee Corporation 
Atlantconsult LLC 
Atos (Taiwan) Ltd 
Atos AG 
Atos Belgium SA 
Atos Bilisim Danismanlik ve Müsteri Hizmetleri San. A.S.
Atos Bulgaria Competency Center EOOD 
Atos Inc. 
Atos India Pvt. Ltd. 
Atos Information Technology (S) Pte Ltd 
Atos Information Technology GmbH 
Atos Information Technology (China) Co., Ltd.
Atos IT Services UK Limited 
Atos It Services 
Atos IT Solutions and Services A/S 
Atos IT Solutions and Services AB 
Atos IT Solutions and Services GmbH 
ATOS IT SOLUTIONS AND SERVICES IBERIA SL 
Atos IT Solutions and Services LLC 
Atos IT Solutions and Services Oy 
Atos IT Solutions and Services, Inc. 
Atos IT Solutions and Services, s.r.o. 
Atos IT Solutions and Services s.r.o.
ATOS IT SOLUTIONS AND SERVICES D.O.O. BEOGRAD
Atos IT Solutions and Services 
Atos IT Solutions Romania SRL 
Atos IT Solutions and Services Limited
Atos Italia S.p.A. 
Atos Nederland B.V. 
Atos Origin FZ LLC 
Atos Polska S.A. 
Atos Polska S.A. 
Atos Saudi Arabia 
Atos Serviços de Tecnologia da Informaçao do Brasil Ltda.
AUGUSTA REEVES 
Axxis Consulting (S) Pte Ltd 
B4B Solutions GmbH 
B4B Solutions GmbH 
Bluekey Seidor (Pty) Ltd. 
BSG Partners Co., Ltd. 
BULL SAS 
CAPGEMINI (CHINA) CO., LTD 
Capgemini AB 
Capgemini Argentina S.A. 
Capgemini Australia Pty Limited 
Capgemini Belgium N.V. 
Capgemini Brasil S.A. 
CAPGEMINI ESPAÑA, S.L. 
Capgemini Italia S.p.A. 
Capgemini Mexico, S. de R.L. de C.V. 
Capgemini Nederland B.V. 
Capgemini Norge AS 
CAPGEMINI PORTUGAL - SERVIÇOS DE CONSULTORIA E INFORMÁTICA, S.A.
Capgemini Services Malaysia Sdn Bhd 
Capgemini Singapore Pte Ltd 
Capgemini Technologies LLC 
Capgemini Technologies LLC 
Capgemini Technology Services India Ltd. Block 2&3,Plot no IT3,IT4, 2nd &
CAPGEMINI TECHNOLOGY SERVICES 
Capgemini UK Plc 
Celonis SE 
CenturyLink CenturyTel LLC
CIDEON Software & Services GmbH & Co.KG 
Cisco Systems, Inc. 
COMPAGNIE IBM FRANCE SAS 
CPM BRAXIS TECNOLOGIA LTDA. 
Crystal Solutions S.A. 
CSC Computer Sciences Brasil S.A. 
CTAC België NV 
Ctac N.V. 
DC Extended Delivery S. de R.L. de C.V. 
Deloitte & Co. S.A. 
Deloitte & Touche Consulting Group ICS Pte Ltd.
Deloitte & Touche S.R.L. 
Deloitte AB 
Deloitte Asesores y Consultores Ltda 
Deloitte Assessoria e Consultoria Ltda 
Deloitte Business Solutions S.A 
Deloitte Consulting & Advisory Deloitte Entity
Deloitte Consulting (Pty) Ltd 
Deloitte Consulting (SEA) Sdn Bhd 
Deloitte Consulting B.V. 
DELOITTE CONSULTING CR, S.A. 
Deloitte Consulting ehf. 
Deloitte Consulting Ltd. 
Deloitte Consulting Product Services LLC 
Deloitte Consulting Pte Ltd 
Deloitte Consulting S.A. 
Deloitte Consulting S.r.l 
DELOITTE CONSULTING VIETNAM CO., LTD 
DELOITTE CONSULTORES, S.A. 
Deloitte Inc. 
DELOITTE LIMITED 
Deloitte LLP 
Deloitte Servicios Profesionales Ltda 
Deloitte Tax & Consulting 
Deloitte Technology Limited 
Deloitte Tohmatsu Consulting LLC 
Deloitte Touche Tohmatsu 
Deloitte 
Detay Danismanlik Bilgisayar Hizmetleri San. ve Dis Tic.A.S.
Deutsche Telekom Healthcare and Security Solutions GmbH
DSC Software AG 
Dunn Solutions Group 
DXC Technologies 
DXC Technology (Middle East) FZ LLC
DXC Technology Austria GmbH 
DXC Technology Czech Republic s.r.o. 
DXC Technology Deutschland GmbH 
DXC TECHNOLOGY FRANCE 
DXC Technology Japan, Ltd. 
DXC Technology Services LLC 
DXC Technology Services Singapore Pte. Ltd.
DXC Technology Services Vietnam Company Limited
DXC Technology Spain, S.A. 
DXD APPLICATIONS AND IT SOLUTIONS, S.L. 
DynaSys Solutions Ltd. 
Edenhouse Solutions Limited 
Edraky LLC Edraky
EIT Services India Private Limited 
Enterprise IT Services MiddleEast FZ LLC 
ENTERPRISE SERVICES BRASIL SERVICOS DE TECNOLOGIA LTDA
Enterprise Services d.o.o. Beograd 
EntServ Enterprise Services Mexico S. de R.L. de C.V.
ENTSERV PHILIPPINES,INC 
EPAM Systems, Inc. 
Everis Chile S.A. 
Everis México, S. de R.L. de C.V. 
Everis Peru Sociedad Anonima Cerrada 
Excellence Delivered ExD Pvt. Ltd 
EY Brightree Sdn. Bhd. 
Fasttrack ERP Solutions Inc. 
FastTrack Solutions, Inc. 
FUJITSU LIMITED 
GE Digital 
Hewlett Packard Colombia LTDA. 
Hewlett Packard Enterprise Company 
Hewlett Packard Enterprise India Private Limited
Hewlett Packard Enterprise Polska sp. z o.o.
HEWLETT PACKARD FRANCE SAS 
Hewlett-Packard (M) Sdn Bhd 
Hewlett-Packard (Schweiz) GmbH 
Hewlett-Packard (Thailand) Ltd. 
Hewlett-Packard HK SAR Limited 
Hitachi Vantara Corporation 
Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd 
IBM (China) Company Limited 
IBM ARGENTINA SRL 
IBM Australia Limited 
IBM Belgium B.V.B.A. 
IBM Brasil - Indústria, Máquinas e Serviços Limitada.
IBM BULGARIA EOOD 
IBM Canada Limited 
IBM Ceska republika, spol. s r.o. 
IBM China / Hong Kong Limited (Partner) 
IBM Corporation International Technical
IBM Danmark ApS 
IBM de Chile S.A.C. 
IBM De Colombia & Cia. S.C.A. 
IBM del Peru S.A.C. 
IBM Deutschland GmbH 
IBM Eastern Europa/Asia Ltd. 
IBM Eesti OÜ 
IBM Engineering Technology (Shanghai) Co Ltd.
IBM GLOBAL SERVICES ESPAÑA, S.A. 
IBM Global Services ve Teknoloji Hizmetleri
IBM Hellas S.A. 
IBM HRVATSKA D.O.O. 
IBM India Pvt Ltd 
IBM Int. Business Machines AS 
IBM International Business Machines doo 
IBM Ireland Ltd 
IBM Italia S.p.A. 
IBM Italia S.p.A 
IBM Italia SpA (Pakistan) 
IBM Japan Services Company Ltd. 
IBM Japan, Ltd. 
IBM Korea, INC. 
IBM Malaysia Sdn Bhd 
IBM Middle East FZ LLC 
IBM Middle East FZ-LLC SaudiArabiaBranch 
IBM Polska Sp. z o.o. 
IBM Qatar SSC 
IBM Romania SRL 
IBM Schweiz AG 
IBM Singapore Pte Ltd 
IBM Slovenija d.o.o. 
IBM South Africa (Pty) Ltd 
IBM Svenska AB 
IBM Taiwan Corporation 
IBM Thailand Co., Ltd. 
IBM United Kingdom Limited 
IBM World Trade Corporation 
ICM.S S.r.l. 
Illumiti Corp. 
Illumiti Inc 
Illumiti One Inc 
Implema AB 
In Cloud Solutions Ltd 
Intelligroup Saudi Arabia Company Ltd 
IPS Co., Ltd. 
ISS Consulting (Thailand) Ltd. 
Itelis d.o.o. 
itelligence a/s 
Itelligence AB 
Itelligence AG, Niederlassung Wien 
itelligence AG 
itelligence AG 
Itelligence AS 
Itelligence Benelux Holding BV 
Itelligence Bilgi Sistemleri A.S. 
Itelligence Business Solutions (UK) Limited
Itelligence Business Solutions 
itelligence Business Solutions Canada, Inc.
itelligence Consulting (Shanghai) Ltd
ITELLIGENCE FRANCE 
itelligence Hungary Informatika Kft. 
Itelligence India Software Solutions Private Limited
Itelligence LLC 
itelligence Outsourcing MSC Sdn Bhd 
itelligence Slovakia, s.r.o. 
Itelligence Software Solutions 
itelligence Sp. z o.o. 
itelligence, a.s. 
Itelligence, Inc. 
itelligence 
KBJ S.A. 
KWP Austria GmbH 
KWP INSIDE HR GmbH 
Lenovo Global Technology HK Limited 
MIBCON a.s. 
MSS Seidor Colombia S.A.S. 
MSS Seidor Peru SAC 
MSS Seidor, S.L. 
Myanmar Information Technology Pte Ltd.
NetApp, Inc. 
NTT DATA Business Solutions Malaysia Sdn Bhd
NTT DATA Business Solutions Australia Pty Ltd
NTT DATA Business Solutions Singapore Pte Ltd
NTT DATA Romania SA 
NTT DATA VIETNAM CO. LTD 
Nutanix Inc 
OOO T-Systems CIS 
Open Text Corporation 
ORBIT Gesellschaft für Applikations- und Informationssysteme mbH
OSC Smart Integration GmbH 
OSIsoft, LLC 
Oxygen Business Solutions Ltd 
Oxygen Business Solutions Pty Ltd 
Pearl Norge AS 
Price Waterhouse & Co Asesores de Empresas S.R.L
PricewaterhouseCoopers Advisory N.V. 
PricewaterhouseCoopers Advisory S.p.A. 
PricewaterhouseCoopers Business Solutions SA
PricewaterhouseCoopers Consulting (Australia) Pty Limited
PricewaterhouseCoopers Consulting (Singapore) PTE LTD
PricewaterhouseCoopers Consulting (Thailand) Ltd.
PriceWaterhouseCoopers Consultores Auditores SpA
PricewaterhouseCoopers GmbH Wirtschaftsprüfungsgesellschaft
PricewaterhouseCoopers Inc 
PricewaterhouseCoopers LLP 
PriceWaterhouseCoopers LLP 
PricewaterhouseCoopers LLP 
PricewaterhouseCoopers Management Consulting (Shanghai) Limited
Pricewaterhousecoopers Management Consultants SRL
PricewaterhouseCoopers Private Limited 
Pricewaterhousecoopers, S.C. 
PricewaterhouseCoopers Česká republika s.r.o.
Process Partner AG 
Proquire LLC 
PT  Accenture 
PT Deloitte Consulting 
PT IBM Indonesia 
PT Soltius Indonesia 
Pure Storage Inc. 
PwC Consulting LLC 
PWC Consulting Services (M) Sdn Bhd. 
PwC Enterprise Advisory cvba/scrl 
PwC Société coopérative 
Questionmark Computing Limited 
QZing Technology (Beijing) Company Limited
Real Consulting IT Business Solutions SA 
Red Hat, Inc. 
RED POINT SOFTWARE SOLUTIONS SRL 
Redwood Alliances B.V. 
SAS Institute Inc. 
SAVIC Technologies Private Limited 
Seidor Chile S.A. 
Seidor Colombia SAS 
Seidor Consulting Peru SAC 
Seidor Consulting SA 
SEIDOR CONSULTING, S.L. 
Seidor Crystalis - Tecnologia da Informação S.A.
Seidor Crystalis Costa Rica 
Seidor Maroc, SARL 
SEIDOR MEXICO SAPI de CV 
Seidor Middle East & North Africa FZ-LLC 
Seidor Portugal, Lda 
Seidor S.A. 
Seidor UK Ltd 
Seidor Uruguay Informatica S.A 
Seidor USA Corp 
Servicios Informáticos Itelligence, S.A
Shanghai Acloudear Info. Tech. Co., Ltd. 
SOA PEOPLE SA/NV 
SOA PEOPLE SAS 
Société Conseil Groupe LGS. 
Sofigate Business Technologies Oy 
SOFTINSA - ENGENHARIA DE SOFTWARE AVANÇADO, LDA
SUSE Software Solutions Germany GmbH 
Syniti 
Systex Corporation 
T-Systems Austria GesmbH 
T-Systems do Brasil Ltda 
T-Systems International GmbH 
T-SYSTEMS ITC IBERIA, S.A.U. 
T-Systems Malaysia Sdn. Bhd. 
T-Systems Multimedia Solutions GmbH 
T-Systems México, S.A. de C.V. 
T-Systems Nederland B.V. 
T-Systems North America, Inc. 
T-Systems P.R.China Ltd. 
T-Systems Polska Spolka z o.o. 
T-Systems Schweiz AG 
T-Systems Singapore Pte Ltd 
T-Systems South Africa (Pty) Ltd 
TalentChamp Consulting GmbH 
TEAMIDEA GROUP LLC 
TECNILÓGICA ECOSISTEMAS, S.A.U. 
Telekom Deutschland GmbH 
Terralink Technologies LLC 
The Hackett Group d/b/a Answerthink, Inc.
unit-IT Dienstleistungs GmbH & Co KG
Utopia Global, Inc. 
VIEWNEXT S.A. 
Vistex, Inc. 
Westrocon Seidor (PTY) Ltd 
Öhrlings PricewaterhouseCoopers AB 
3Hold Technologies, SL 
4process AG 
Aareon Deutschland GmbH 
AB Consulting Group Zrt. 
Abacus Cambridge Partners (Middle East) Ltd.
Abacus Cambridge Partners Saudia LLC 
Abacus Consulting Technology Pvt Ltd
AbacusConsulting 
abat AG 
abc Consulting S.A. 
ABeam Consulting (Malaysia) Sdn Bhd 
ABeam Consulting (Shanghai) Co., Ltd. 
ABeam Consulting (Thailand) Limited 
ABeam Consulting Ltd. 
Abeo Vietnam Co., Ltd 
Abide Consult AG 
abilis GmbH 
ABM Global Solutions, Inc. 
Abracon GmbH 
Absoft Limited 
Acando Consulting AB 
Accely Consulting India Private Limited 
Acclimation Pty Ltd 
ACEteK Software Limited 
AchieveIT Solutions, Inc. 
ACI Holdings 
ACJ Consulting Co., Ltd. 
Acorel VAR B.V. 
ACRON Bilisim A.S. 
Actualisap Consultores Bolivia S.A. 
Acuma Solutions Ltd 
Adesso SE 
ADP Consultores S.R.L. 
AdS Consulting, Beratung für angewandte Informationsverarbeitung GmbH
Advanced Applications GmbH 
Advanced Business Software 
Advanced Business Solutions 
Advanced Electronics Company 
Advantech Technologies  Ltd 
Advantic Consultores de sistemas de información S.L.
AEKANSA S.A. SYPSOFT360
AFON Technologies Pte Ltd 
AG Consultancy & Apps Ltd 
Agentil SA 
AGILITA AG 
Agion 
AICOMP Cloud GmbH 
AKT Solutions Ltd 
AL BILAD ARABIA CO. LTD. 
ALEXANDER MOORE S.A. 
Alfa Sistemas de Gestao LTDA 
Alfacloud LTD 
all4cloud GmbH & Co. KG 
Allgeier ES France 
Allos S.r.l. 
alogis AG 
Altab S.A. 
Altaflux Corporation 
ALTEA UP S.r.l. 
Altevie Technologies S.r.l. 
ALTIM TECNOLOGIAS DE LA INFORMACIÓN,S.L. 
AMS Advanced Management Solutions Ltd 
AMS Solutions Limited 
AMT - CONSULTING, S.A. 
Anda Srl 
ANSI Information Systems, Inc. 
anthesis GmbH 
AO "ECOPSY" 
AODYS 
APPCENTRIC Solutions Inc. 
applied international informatics GmbH 
APPTechnology Experts, Inc. 
APSIA 
apsolut GmbH 
Arago Consulting Iberia 
ARAGO CONSULTING SAS 
Arete Bilgisayar, Otomasyon Egitim ve Danismanlik Hizm. San. Tic. Ltd. Sti.
Arete Global Company Branch FZ-LLC 
Arineo GmbH 
Arinso Iberica S.A.U. 
Arithnea GmbH 
Arvato Systems GmbH 
AS Emergn 
ASAP soft 
ASAR AMERICA INC. 
Ascarii Ltd 
Ascentium Corporation DBA SMITH
AScorpi GmbH 
Asecom B.V. 
ASG Group Limited 
Aspire HR Inc. 
ASPN CO.,LTD. 
Attune Consulting USA, Inc. 
Aubay Italia S.p.A. 
avantum Consult AG 
Avectris AG 
Avtenta, napredne poslovne rešitve, d.o.o.
Axians ICT Austria GmbH 
Axians NEO Solutions & Technology GmbH 
Axianseu II Digital CONSULTING SA 
Axxiom Soluções Tecnológicas S.A 
Ayesa Advanced Technologies, S.A. 
b1 consulting GmbH 
Babiel GmbH 
Backoffice Associates 
BAITCON S.A. 
Baraka IT Solutions (Pty) Ltd 
BC SKILLS CONSULTING 
BCI Consulting SRL 
BCS Business Consulting Services Kft. 
BDO Unicon Business Solutions AO 
BDO Ziv Haft Consulting @ Management Ltd 
be one solutions Americas Inc. 
be one solutions Deutschland GmbH 
be one solutions Japan K.K. 
Be1Eye GmbH 
BearingPoint GmbH 
Beijing AVA Technology Inc. 
Beijing Ether Electronics Group Co., Ltd.
Beijing Faujor Technology Co., Ltd. 
Beijing Pactera Services Limited 
Beijing Shunshiheng Technology Development Co,. Ltd.
BENOY LLC 
Bestcom Infotech Corporation 
Beyond Technologies Consulting Inc. 
BEYOND TECHNOLOGIES 
BGP Management Consulting S.p.A. 
BH Consulting Co., Ltd. 
Bilot Oyj 
Birchman Solutions Ltd 
BizTech Partners Co., Ltd 
Blend IT Consultoria e Serviços em Informática Ltda
Blue Pencil Consulting Pty Ltd 
Bluekey Seidor (K) Limited 
BluePrint Technologies Private Limited 
Bluetree Solutions Pty Ltd 
BluLeader Pty Ltd 
BMS Global Services LLC 
bneXt Inc. 
BosCloud Jiangsu Science and Technology Co., Ltd.
Boyum IT A/S 
Bramasol, Inc. 
Brave New World Consulting Pty Ltd t/as BNW Consulting
bridgX 
Bright Business Partners 
Britehouse a Division of Dimension Data (pty) Ltd
BS&C 
BSGOne Co., Ltd. BSGOne
BTC Bilisim Hizmetleri A.S. 
BTC Business Technology Consulting  AG
BUSINESS AT WORK 
Business Process Solutions SA de CV Xamai
Business Service Center LLC 
BXT Solution Co., Ltd 
BXTI Soluciones en Tecnología de Información S.A. de C.V.
C2E Teknoloji Servisleri Ticaret Anonim Sirketi
Caleo Consulting GmbH 
Camelot ITLab GmbH 
CANCOM Managed Services GmbH 
CAPLAN Corporation 
Castaliaz Technologies Private Limited 
CBL CONSULTING 
CCelera s.r.l. 
CEGB Corporation 
Celeritech Mexico SAPI de CV 
CEO Consultoría, S.R.L 
CEREALOG 
CGI Suomi Oy 
CGI Sverige AB 
Chain Services TI S.A.C. Csti S.A.C.
Chengdu Biz-United Information Technology Co., Ltd.
China National Software and Service Co., Ltd.
Chinasoft Technology (Shenzhen) Corporation Limited
cHReative Consultoria LTDA 
Cibernetica, S.A. 
Citek Technology Joint Stock Company 
Clarex Srl 
Clariba Consulting S.L.U. 
Clientis AG 
Clients First Business Solutions LLC 
Clockwork Business Solutions Private Limited
Clockwork Inc. 
Cloudera Limited 
Cloudway Consulting Private Limited 
CM CONSULTING 
CNBM Technology Co., Ltd 
CNT Management Consulting AG 
Codestone Solutions Ltd 
CODILOG - ELIANCE 
Cogniscient Business Solutions Private Limited
Cognitus Consulting LLC 
Columbus Systems GmbH 
COMLINE Computer + Softwarelösungen SE 
COMMON MANAGEMENT SOLUTIONS, S.L. 
Complete Business Solutions 
COMPTA - EQUIPAMENTOS E SERVIÇOS DE INFORMÁTICA, S.A.
Compuage Infocom Limited 
CompuNet, S.A. 
CompuTec S.A. 
Computer Systems Pvt Ltd 
ComSol AG Commercial Solutions
CON.SE s.r.l. 
ConCorn LLC. 
CONPLUS Mittelstandslösungen GmbH 
CONSEILS PLUS 
Conseils-Plus 
Consensus International, LLC 
Consensus S.A.S. 
Consilio GmbH 
consolut.gmbh 
Consulting 4U, s.r.o. 
Consultoría Organizacional S.A.S. 
ConVista Consulting AG 
Cormeta AG 
Corponet Implements, S.A. de C.V. 
Corporacion Saratella, S.A. Vivo Consulting
```

Comment: thanks!! it works, but i still don't understand how it does? if you can help? please. Where does the variable `data` come from in your code? and what it does?

Comment: @AhmadFaraz Actually I've explained above the code. please direct me to the point where you couldn't figure so i can further explain

Comment: Actually I needed to scrape this all data from the search results, but i was not able to, because i have no idea where did the `data` variable came from? and what it does? Also how do we track the `XHR request`                                                                          
   -Name of Company
   -Partner Level (Platinum/Gold/Silver/Bronze)
   -Partner Type
   -Engagement Type
   -Contact Name
   -Contact Phone
   -Contact Email
   -Description
-Website

Comment: @AhmadFaraz answer is updated. let me know if there's anything unclear. I think you know how to loop and access by keys ? yes?

Comment: Fine, can you help me finding the remaining data as well. thank you

Comment: Do all websites got this `json` type of response along with the `html` type response.

Comment: Also you seem to be scraping data from a different URL altogether

Comment: @AhmadFaraz if you taken time to read what about the answer, before running the code. you will find that i described all information! also there's a variable holding a dict of all the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a header with **User-Agent** string to your request. You can do that like this:

```py
url = 'https://partneredge.sap.com/content/partnerfinder/search.html#/search/results?itemsPerPage=10&sortBy=shortname&sortOrder=asc'
header = {
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers = header)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   results = content.find_all('li', {'class': ['search-results__item']})
```