# Beautiful Soup find_all giving empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to webscraping and experimenting to retrieve a title name and value from a site (https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURCHF/?exchange=OANDA)

I am using find_all function of BeautifulSoup which finds me lines for title but returns and empty list for value. My code is shown below:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    url1="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURCHF/?exchange=OANDA"
    html1=urlopen(url1)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, 'lxml')
    name1=soup1.find_all('div', class_="tv-symbol-header__short-title")
    val1=soup1.find_all('div', class_="tabValue-3iOTI9jm")
    print(name1)
    print(val1)
```

Why is it returning empty list.
On inspecting the data at site, it shows "Info" as tabValue-3iOTI9jm
I have taken screenshot which is shown here
[Inspect ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP1p6.jpg)

After running my code, the name1 gets printed but val1 is shown as empty list. Result is shown here
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1lEb.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code as text not as an image.

Comment: Dear Mohammed - would you be so kind to share some of your ideas. We love to hear from you again. - ahhh well now i see you have posted your code. Many thanks

Comment: @ChristianYami , the code is posted above as text. Images are seperate. Please see the gray area

Comment: @MohammadAhmed you aware that the site is loaded via `JavaScript`, therefor `urllib` will not be able to render `JS` on the fly ! you should consider using `selenium` or direct `API`

Comment: @zero  I checked, problem seems to be in reading of html by BeautifulSoup because when i print soup1, required info is not present there so it should return empty list but why is that so and how to solve it

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη , you are right, i previously tried selenium , it was getting it but chromedriver was causing problem so i read online and tried using urllib and it was causing this problem of empty list. Thanks for pointing out. Can you help on how to find API for the above site?

Comment: @MohammadAhmed check below answer with updated call to the `API`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Here's a direct call to the `Back-End` `API`

```py
import requests

data = {"symbols": {"tickers": ["FX_IDC:EURCHF"], "query": {"types": ["forex"]}}, "columns": ["Recommend.All", "RSI", "RSI[1]", "Stoch.K", "Stoch.D", "Stoch.K[1]", "Stoch.D[1]", "CCI20", "CCI20[1]", "ADX", "ADX+DI", "ADX-DI", "ADX+DI[1]", "ADX-DI[1]", "AO", "AO[1]", "Mom", "Mom[1]", "MACD.macd", "MACD.signal",
                                                                                              "Rec.Stoch.RSI", "Stoch.RSI.K", "Rec.WR", "W.R", "Rec.BBPower", "BBPower", "Rec.UO", "UO", "EMA5", "close", "SMA5", "EMA10", "SMA10", "EMA20", "SMA20", "EMA30", "SMA30", "EMA50", "SMA50", "EMA100", "SMA100", "EMA200", "SMA200", "Rec.Ichimoku", "Ichimoku.BLine", "Rec.VWMA", "VWMA", "Rec.HullMA9", "HullMA9"]}
r = requests.post(
    "https://scanner.tradingview.com/forex/scan", json=data).json()

print(r)
```

Output:

```
{'data': [{'s': 'FX_IDC:EURCHF', 'd': [-0.3474026, 40.20328953, 40.7342841, 24.71794872, 32.35897436, 30.23076923, 40.12820513, -71.9887128, -68.01055011, 16.51125049, 14.84157898, 16.77182105, 14.90478566, 16.84324816, -0.00283482, -0.00251176, -0.00017, 0.00098, -0.00161929, -0.00171414, 0, 45.887686, 0, -78.69230769, 0, -0.00475522, 0, 45.51407259, 1.05654604, 1.05526, 1.056942, 1.05734726, 1.058608, 1.05837338, 1.057454, 1.0597646, 1.059502, 1.06326959, 1.0621026, 1.07175293, 1.0747255, 1.08482787, 1.08547945, 0, 1.061735, None, None, 1, 1.05488111]}], 'totalCount': 1}
```

Well, `TradingView` is loaded via `JavaScript` dynamically once the page loads., Therefor, `bs4` will not be able to render `JavaScript` on air..

You should consider using [API](https://www.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/) directly. Or you can use `selenium` approach.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURCHF/?exchange=OANDA")

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tabValue-3iOTI9jm").text

print(element)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
1.05613
```

Comment: Thanks , I did tick the check mark. it was not recorded because my reputation is low. I am sorry

Comment: thanks for correction. Tick Done. I am new here. Btw I studied about api. End points are given in their documentation. I just don't understand how to get base url and i saw you used https://scanner.tradingview.com/forex/scan , how did you generate this link?

Comment: @MohammadAhmed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029502/response-object-doesnt-return-the-data-i-want-to-scrape-from-a-url/61031234#61031234